# Scanner won't read the next line from a file. JAVA

Tags: java, output, bufferedreader

Like the title says, I can get it to write the first thing to the file I want it to, but after that it doesn't write any more. I run it through the debugger, and see that it's not even reading the next line (I know this because it's not filling the array.) I tried manually advancing the pointer (I don't know if that's actually a thing you can do) at the end of the loop with "line = in.readline;", but It just throws a "nosuchelement" exception. Here's my try block"

```
try
  {
     in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lab7input.txt"));

     outNormal = new PrintWriter(new File("normal.txt"));
     outVegetarian = new PrintWriter(new File("vegetarian.txt"));
     outPescetarian = new PrintWriter(new File("pescetarian.txt"));
     outInvalid = new PrintWriter(new File("invalid.txt"));

     String line = in.readLine();
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);

     while (line != null)
     {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            if(st.countTokens() == 3)
            {
                attendee3[0] = sc.next();
                attendee3[1] = sc.next();
                attendee3[2] = sc.next();

                if(Integer.parseInt(attendee3[2]) == 0)
                {
                    outNormal.println(attendee3[0] + " " + attendee3[1]);
                    outNormal.close();
                }
                else if(Integer.parseInt(attendee3[2]) == 1)
                {
                    outVegetarian.println(attendee3[0] + " " + attendee3[1]);
                    outVegetarian.close();
                }
                else if(Integer.parseInt(attendee3[2]) == 2)
                {
                    outPescetarian.println(attendee3[0] + " " + attendee3[1]);
                    outPescetarian.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    outInvalid.println(attendee3[0] + " " + attendee3[1]);
                    outInvalid.close();
                }
            }  
            if(st.countTokens() == 4)
            {
                attendee4[0] = sc.next();
                attendee4[1] = sc.next();
                attendee4[2] = sc.next();

                if(Integer.parseInt(attendee4[3]) == 0)
                {
                    outNormal.println(attendee4[0] + " " + attendee4[1] + " " + attendee4[2]);
                    outNormal.close();
                }
                else if(Integer.parseInt(attendee4[3]) == 1)
                {
                    outVegetarian.println(attendee4[0] + " " + attendee4[1] + " " + attendee4[2]);
                    outVegetarian.close();
                }
                else if(Integer.parseInt(attendee4[3]) == 2)
                {
                    outPescetarian.println(attendee4[0] + " " + attendee4[1] + " " + attendee4[2]);
                    outPescetarian.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    outInvalid.println(attendee4[0] + " " + attendee4[1] + " " + attendee4[2]);
                    outInvalid.close();
                }
            }
            //line = in.readLine();
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is you only read from the file once String line = in.readLine();. I do not think while (line != null ) will not work as you expect because of this.

Comment: That's what I thought, so I added that "line=in.readLine();" part at the end of the loop so it would just read again after it was done. It throws that exception though. It's almost as if it reads through the entire file and has nothing left to read, though I don't see how that's possible...

Comment: if st.countTokens() is not 3 and not 4, then you are just going to loop endlessly

Comment: Even with my added readLine? Wouldn't that just advance it line by line, eventually ending the loop? Regardless, I made sure my next few inputs were 3 or 4 to test this out, and it's still only reading the first :(

Comment: why are you using a scanner and a stringtokenizer?  what is your logic.

Comment: So I can use the countTokens method to determine how many tokens are in a line. I want 3 or 4 for valid input. I guess I could just make a loop with the scanner, but using the tokenizer seemed more efficient.

Comment: You have an error in your; the `st` variable will not be updated to a new line when you call `line = in.readLine();`.  You should either move the instantiation of the tokenizer down to the 'Scanner` or get rid of it altogether like in Java1's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simpler and cleaner way would be

```
 String line = in.readLine();

 while (line != null)
 {
    String arr [] = line.split ();
    if(arr.length == 3)
    {
            attendee3[0] = arr[0];
            attendee3[1] = arr[1];
            attendee3[2] = arr[2];
    }
   // other count code

   line = in.readLine();
 }
```

Comment: I messed with the .split method for a while, couldn't get it to work right. I don't that that's my problem, though, as I get it to read and copy to my array, and then write to the file. My issue is moving the scanner along.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo with my `arr[0]` lines. copy and paste error.  If you are not going to take my advice and simplify things then at least put in some print statements so you know what is happening.

Comment: I have since figured out how the split method works. That is much easier. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `line = in.readLine()` one block below and not in a while block of a scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Not only that, i've had the experience that Scanner can only read in UTF-8 codeded .txt files. so always make sure that they are UTF-8 coded.
If they are not just simply open the file and save it with that coding.